# Problem installing ubuntu 15.10 alongside windows 8.1 on HP 15-ab035AX

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, system-installation, 15.10

I have HP 15-ab035AX pavilion series laptop with window 8.1, 64 bit. I created a bootable flash drive of ubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso, booted my computer to install ubuntu along side windows using the flash drive but it didn't booted properly and shown this before getting hanged ->

[     0.051367] Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0 (expected 1)

^@

Please help me out???

Answer (score 0):

I have an HP 14-b033 and am currently using openSUSE.

I understand the situation you have.

Here is what I did with mine:

USB boot from a flash drive did not work well for me so I tried a different approach. I used the dd approach to transfer my openSUSE iso file to a DVD.

When I reboot, I use F9 as soon as the boot screen starts to select the CD drive with the iso file on it.

I then went through the installation process to install the system to a 20GB partition that had been created earlier for my linux system.

Now if I want to boot win 8.1 I just don't enter the F9 and it boots to 8.1.

If I try to select the 8.1 file from the F9 then I have to select the OS boot at the top of the list.

Where is GRUB?

Broken and can't make it work.

At least I have linux on my HP and windows for tax programs.